# Выдает ошибку при вводе в input, клас Scanner Java . Int или других переменных

Tags: java, scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String name = scanner.nextLine(); //Nick
        int age = scanner.nextInt();// 25
        String education = scanner.nextLine(); //secondary
        int experience = scanner.nextInt(); //3
        String fusion = scanner.nextLine();// fusion dishes
// после третьего параметра idea выбрасывает ошибку InputMismatchException. не могу понять как заменить и на что переменные цифр.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine(); //Nick
        int age = scanner.nextInt();// 25
        scanner.nextLine();
        String education = scanner.nextLine(); //secondary
        int experience = scanner.nextInt(); //3
        scanner.nextLine();
        String fusion = scanner.nextLine();// fusion dishes
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое